# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:"\php\php_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be loaded

Tags: php, wamp

I'm trying to upgrade php 5.4.14 from php 5.4.3 in wamp server 2.2e.

- I have downloaded [`php-5.4.14-Win32-VC9-x86`](http://windows.php.net/download/) ([thread safe](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-debug-pack-5.4.14-Win32-VC9-x86.zip)).
- Extracted it under `C:\wamp\bin\php`.
- Copied `wampserver.conf` from `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3` to
  `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.14`.
- Renamed `php.ini-development` to `phpForApache.ini`.
  -The port number the wamp server has been [changed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13620157/1037210) in the `http.conf` file to 8087 from its default 80.

This is mentioned [here](http://www.bluefrog.ca/2012/03/adding-php-5-4-0-final-support-to-wampserver/) though it is about upgrading from php 5.3.5 to php 5.4.0.

After this, Restarting of the wamp server and services all over again has all been done and those two versions appeared in the menu php->versions (which is opened when the icon of the server is clicked).

But when I attempt to enable a library like `php_mysql` or `php_mysqli`, a warning message box appears.

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:"\php\php_mysql.dll' -
>   The specified module could not be loaded.

I have also tried to removing the semicolon before them in the `php.ini` file but to no avail.

I'm running Microsoft Windows XP Professional Version 2002, service pack 3.

Where might be the problem?

---

**EDIT:**

I have changed `extension_dir` from `C:\php` to `c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.14\ext\` in `php.ini` as the answer below indicates and the library is now loaded correctly but it says,

> 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

though the user name and the password are the same as they are in MySQL in the `config.inc.php` file under phpmyadmin. I have also tried to restart MySQL56 service from Control Panel->Services(Local) but it keeps giving the same error. Does someone know why this happens?

Comment: Why do you want to enable ext/mysql anyway? [The PHP development explicitly discourages it's use for new projects.](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: @Gordon : It is because my project was initially built in php `5.2.x` using `mysql_*` functions. I also wanted to keep it running.

Comment: If the project is worth the effort, change to mysqli or pdo to be future proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `phpinfo()`.
Find line: Loaded Configuration File
and look at extension_dir too.
If it is `c:\php` and it is not the folder you have your php installed in then open the loaded conf file and edit the line

`extension_dir = C:\php`

to

`extension_dir = C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4\ext`

or something similar.
Restart WAMP.

Comment: Yes this has been changed to `extension_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.14/ext/"` in `php.ini` and the library is now loaded correctly but it says, "*#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)*" though the user name and the password are the same as they are in MySQL in the `config.inc.php` file in phpmyadmin. I have also tried to restart MySQL56 service from Control Panel->Services(Local) but it keeps giving the same error. Do you know why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

you should make sure libmysql.dll is installed on your computer, you can look for it under C:\Windows\System32 (in Windows 7, or the equivalent in other windows versions). This is specified in the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php). You can download libmysql.dll [here](http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?libmysql). This bug took me quite some time to solve. hope it helps.

Comment: I can't remember right now but perhaps I gave a wrong path somewhere. Otherwise, everything was fine. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Run `phpinfo()`. Find line: Loaded Configuration File and look at `extension_dir` too. If it is `c:\php` and it is not the folder you have your php installed in then open the loaded conf file and edit the line

```
extension_dir = C:\php
```

to

```
extension_dir = C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4\ext
```

or something similar. Restart WAMP.